# Clean up PHP & MYSQL code (Picked up by Swift as blog reader iOS app)

Tags: php, mysql, json

New to PHP and was just wondering if any improvements can be made, maybe increase efficiency or just clean up code?

I know I'm using an old MYSQL maybe we can update it. Just want to make sure the connection can be as best to its ability. Also, if you can, can you explain on how to improve security?

The JSON gets picked up by Swift iOS app.

```
<?php

$dbhost = "website";
$dbuser = "user";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "database";

$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);

// Checking if connection can be established
if(!$connection){

    die("Connection Failed");

} else {

// Selecting Database
$dbconnect = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);

// Checking if it can connect to Database
if(!$dbconnect){

    die("Unable to connect to Database");

} else {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM blogs";
    $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $records= array();

    // Loop and check all records and add to array
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {

        $records[] = $r;
    }

    // Output data as JSON
    echo json_encode($records);
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Please **describe what the code does in the title**. Everyone here want to "make code more efficient and to clean it up".

Comment: You have an `else` statement after a `die()` statement, which is not needed because if the IF statement hits the `die()` the page will stop loading, so you can eliminate 2 lines of code with that. You can do the same with the next `if-else` statement. Also, you are not actually displaying any errors if your connection fails, it just says `Connection Failed` instead of something useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: I updated my answer with a few refactors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
<?php
    $dbhost     = "website";
    $dbuser     = "user";
    $dbpass     = "password";
    $dbname     = "database";
    $connection = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //Kill page if connection could not be established
    //I also added mysql_error() for it to display an error if there was an issue, so you can troubleshoot.
    if(!$connection) { 
        die("Connection Failed:" . mysql_error()); 
    }

    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
    //Same as before, kill page if there was an issue, and display an error.
    //No need for the IF-ELSE statements, if the `die()` function is hit, the page stops loading anyways.
    if(!$dbconnect) { 
        die("Unable to connect to Database: " . mysql_error()); 
    }

    $query     = "SELECT * FROM blogs";
    $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $records   = array();
    // Loop and check all records and add to array
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
        $records[] = $r;
    }
    // Output data as JSON
    echo json_encode($records);
?>
```

But I **highly** recommend switching to `mysqli_*` or PDO statements:

**Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

---

Here is a refactor to `mysqli_*`

```
<?php
    $dbhost     = "website";
    $dbuser     = "user";
    $dbpass     = "password";
    $dbname     = "database";

    $records   = array();

    $connection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    if($connection->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $connection->connect_error . ']');
    }
    $query     = "SELECT * FROM blogs";
    if(!$result = $connection->query($query)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $connection->error . ']');
    }
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $records[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($records);
?>
```

There are a couple of differences here, the first connection checks for an actual connection to the database AND to the table in 1 statement.

Another difference is it shows an error specifically for the query if there was a problem, and not for a table connection error in the 2nd error check.

---

Here is a PDO refactor:

> NOTE: I don't actively develop with PDO, I may have missed something here.

```
<?php
    $dbhost     = "website";
    $dbuser     = "user";
    $dbpass     = "password";
    $dbname     = "database";
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $records   = array();

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $opt);

    $query     = "SELECT * FROM blogs";
    $stmt = $pdo->query($query);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $records[] = $row;
    }
?>
```

Comment: @BroSimple I generally find `mysqli_*` much easier to write than the old `mysql_*` statements.

Comment: It's a lot less code but performance is the same to `mysql_*` ?

Comment: @BroSimple No, performance is better with `mysqli_*`, especially when using [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as it is more optimized.

Comment: @BroSimple Also, it's not really less code. I just took out all the comments. The difference in code is about 15 characters. Each are 11 lines if you take out all of the comments, and between 628 and 643 characters. So it is a tiny bit shorter to use `mysqli_*`. PDO is a few characters shorter but more lines.

Comment: I will be learning more about `mysqli` thanks again!

Comment: lolwut... am i completely missing it or is there nothing to prepare here? you're suggesting he use a prepared statement in a query that has exactly zero parameters to prepare????

Comment: Also, this isn't Javascript, bandwidth is no issue. In other words there is no benefit to having shorter code.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. There is a benefit to efficiently short code, being easier to maintain because _less code_. Also, I did not suggest for him to use prepared statements in this situation, I was just telling him they _exist_ and should be used whenever possible. Even if there is no legit reason to have shorter code, some people still strive to have short functional code.

Comment: Let me re-phrase. Not only is there no benefit to having the shortest possible code, it is actually **bad practice** to have super short code. Golfing every line doesn't make it easier to maintain, it does the opposite.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Shorter code does not necessarily mean golfing. It can also mean more effecient code, there are many ways to do any operation, some slower than others, some shorter than others, some longer than others, etc. I think the goal is to have the shortest and most functional code that is the easiest to maintain. And my length comparisons were completely trivial, I agree in this case it doesn't matter. As you say there is "no benefit" from having short code, there is also "no benefit" of having excessively long code.

Comment: you're the one claiming that there is some correlation between code length and code quality. in javascript that is true for bandwidth purposes, in PHP there is no correlation whatsoever.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I have never said there was a correlation. In fact I even said that my length comparisons were trivial.